# Creating using Html Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I want to create Html helper that will display inner content only if user in role,
Something like this:

```
@using(Html.AdminBlock()) {

}
```

And the code in the block will shown only if user in role...

How I can done it?

If you didn't understand what I mean here example, I want that those 2 codes will return equal result:

```
@if(Html.IsUserInRole("Admin")) {
    <span>hey</span>
}
```

.

```
@using(Htm.RoleBlock()) {
    <span>hey</span>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with an HTML helper that is returning `IDisposable`. The reason for that is because its body will **always** be rendered. You cannot conditionally exclude the body from being rendered in such a statement:

```
@using(Htm.RoleBlock()) {
    <span>hey</span>
}
```

Besides, the following looks readable enough:

```
@if(Html.IsUserInRole("Admin")) {
    <span>hey</span>
}
```

or you could write a helper that will return a boolean value and could be used like that:

```
@if(Html.IsAdmin()) {
    <span>hey</span>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update 2

So you want to keep as much logic out of the view as possible, in this case you can just pull the if conditions out of the view and into a `HtmlHelper` extension method.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static bool IsAdmin(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
@if (Html.IsAdmin()) {
    ...
}
```

### Update

If what you want to only output something if a user is in a role this sort of helper is completely overkill. You should go for a simple `if` statement in your view.

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")) {
    ...
}
```

### Making a custom helper

I posted a [blog post](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/09/custom-helper-for-surrounding-block-in.html) about this very topic last year where I opened up the ASP.NET MVC source to see how `BeginForm()` was put together and made my own. Here are the highlights, this will allow you to wrap a `<div>` around a block in an MVC view.

```
public class MvcDiv : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly FormContext _originalFormContext;
    private readonly ViewContext _viewContext;
    private readonly TextWriter _writer;

    public MvcDiv(ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        if (viewContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("viewContext");
        }

        _viewContext = viewContext;
        _writer = viewContext.Writer;
        _originalFormContext = viewContext.FormContext;
        viewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();

        Begin();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Begin()
    {
        _writer.Write("<div>");
    }

    private void End()
    {
        _writer.Write("</div>");
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            _disposed = true;
            End();

            if (_viewContext != null)
            {
                _viewContext.OutputClientValidation();
                _viewContext.FormContext = _originalFormContext;
            }
        }
    }

    public void EndForm()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
}
```

Then put this extension method somewhere:

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcDiv BeginDiv(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        return new MvcDiv(htmlHelper.ViewContext);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginDiv())
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: But I won't to hide the div I want to simply not to render it.

Comment: Updated, you should just use `@if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin"))`

Comment: This what I don't want to do, I want that all the Logic (if) will outside the view...

Comment: Updated again with another solution.

Comment: You don't understand I want to remove all If sentences out of View

Comment: So you want to use `using` because it's fancier than `if`? Why do you want to remove the `if` statements when it's providing you the functionality you desire.

Comment: Because The logic & If sentences must be out of view, in controller. I can create helper to render each block but it stupid... I want helper that will work on every block..

Comment: Well according to Darin (the highest rep ASP.NET MVC answerer), you can't do it. Being so pedantic about things like this isn't a good thing and is in fact counter-productive. If you're so serious about all `if` statements out of the view then it looks like you're going to need two separate views with an `if` in the controller to say which to render.